# How to make an indicator function or handle for glmfit?

Tags: matlab, handle, glm, indicator

I have a question about creating a handle or indicator function. I have a X matrix that contains 4 explanatory variables and one column (the last one, column 5) of ones and twos that indicates if the observation belongs to group 1 by 1 or group 2 by 2. I want to perform 2 glmfit. One for the observations belonging to group 1, and one for the observations belonging to group 2. I thus need some kind of indicator function so that the glmfit will only calculate the observations of the specific group. Can somebody help me how I can so this? I make use of the following glmfit:

```
[B1, dev, stats1] = glmfit(X(:,1:4), Y, 'binomial', 'link', 'logit');
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the following do the job?

```
indicator = X(:, 5)
[B1, dev, stats1] = glmfit(X(indicator==1,1:4), Y, 'binomial', 'link', 'logit');
[B2, dev, stats2] = glmfit(X(indicator==2,1:4), Y, 'binomial', 'link', 'logit');
```

In the above, `X(indicator==1, 1:4)` employs what is called logical indexing, see also [here](http://The%20following%20uses%20what%20is%20called%20logical%20indexing%20to%20return%20a%20subarray%20of%20X). It provides a submatrix of X, consisting of only the rows where `indicator` has an entry of 1.